# What does Darwin mean by the sentence below?

Tags: meaning

In Origin of the Species, Darwin writes

"A group does not reappear after it has once disappeared; or its existence, as long as it lasts, is continuous .”

I can't tease out the meaning of the second clause. Elsewhere in the book Darwin writes

"When a species has once disappeared from  the face of the earth, we have reason to believe that the same identical form never reappears." This is close to the first statement, but perfectly clear.

Comment: He's giving two ways of saying the same thing.  The "group" cannot disappear and reappear -- it's existence is continuous.

Comment: **First clause**: *When it is gone, it is gone forever.* **Second clause**: *"Continuous" means "never having been gone".* **Therefore**: If it is gone, it is not continuous.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat OK. If it is one, it is not two. I'll have to settle for that.

Answer (score 1):

Lexico defines [continuous](https://www.lexico.com/definition/continuous) as:

> 1 Forming an unbroken whole; without interruption.

So, the group's existence is without interruption: there is no break in its existence after which it comes back into existence.

Comment: That's problem with understanding the sentence structure. _there is **no** break after which it comes back into existence_ = _There is **no such thing** as a group coming back into existence after a break / interruption in its existence_

Comment: @DW256 It may well be the sentence structure. The first clause is followed by a semicolon and or. The "or" says to me an alternative is being given, but an alternative to what? "A group does not  reappear after it has disappeared"? Then, "A group does not reappear . . . after its existence is continuous." (I guess that could be the meaning but it's pretty slight) I think that "as long as it lasts," in this sentence is a redefining of "existence." It's not restrictive, so the clause should work without it. It may ust be me.

Comment: @KannE What kind of professor? Was the prof saying that  "permanent interruptions"  is self contradictory in the sense of language?

Comment: @KanneE No. Existence is loathsome. Ask anyone.

Comment: @KanneE BTW, I wasn't being cute about your professor. I wanted to know whether science or English. "Permanent interruptions" might be a term objected to for different reasons.

Comment: @KanneE Fuck. Oxymoron.

Comment: @Zan700, I think the problem is that you are interpreting *or* as introducing some scenario that is an alternative to the scenario described by what precedes it, while it, in fact, introduces an alternative **formulation** of the same idea. Try replacing 'or', with 'in other words'; does that make the sentence clearer?

Comment: @jsw29 Right. If "or" was instead "in other words," or "or in other words," the meaning would be clear. Can "or" in itself mean those phrases?

Comment: @Zan700, the dictionary definitions include that meaning; my impression is that it may have been more common in the past than now, but I don't have any definite proof of that.

Comment: @jsw29 Interesting. I've only come across or used that way in this one instance. Did you know that before looking it up? What dictionary?

Comment: Lexico (Oxford): 'introducing a synonym or explanation of a preceding word or phrase'. Merriam-Webster: 'the equivalent or substitutive character of two words or phrases'.